# Can't seem to change CSS sub menu code?

Tags: css

Hello I need help trying to change the sub nav color hover. I've tried to write code but it only changes the color or the full nav.

When I change it in my CSS it only changes the background color not the hover, and then when I tried to change the hover it changed for the full header menu and the sub nav. I want to change the hover only the the sub nav.

```css
header li > a:hover{
color:#888888;
}

header li > a #active{
color:#888888;
}

header li ul{
overflow: hidden; display: none; background: #f9f9f9; z-index:20;
}

header li ul li a{
line-height:50px;
padding-left:30px; 
width:260px;
}

header li:hover ul{
position: absolute; padding: 0; display: block; width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It's a little hard to decypher the css without the HTML. Could you post an example of the linked HTML?

Comment: I can already tell you that your selector is wrong: `header li > a #active` should probably be `header li > a:active` unless you actually have an `active` ID on a child element of your `a` element, which wouldn't be valid HTML anyway.

Comment: add your mark-up bro

Comment: @mas add your html here

Comment: ok I added a screen shot below

Answer (score 0):

not clear about your question. do you wanna change submenu color on hover

```
 header li > ul > li > a:hover {background:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

no this only changes the background to the sub nav not the hover. Here is a screen shot of the HTML. thanks everyone

### [Heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q06sP.png)